# Append values into array of objects based on some condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects like this

```
[
  {
    "monthlyData": [
      {
        "dateYear": "2020-07",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "45bf4792-c5a5-44ed-b7e8-57557c4f30ee",
            "date": "2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z",
            "transactionId": "160",
            "amount": 70,
            "active": 1,
            "createdAt": "2020-07-14T02:55:43.988Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
            "version": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "hashId": "4"
  },
  {
    "monthlyData": [
      {
        "dateYear": "2020-08",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "38fe3c68-e6aa-4c57-b4d7-dc6c4f597269",
            "date": "2020-08-13T00:00:00.000Z",
            "transactionId": "146",
            "active": 1,
            "createdAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
            "version": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "hashId": "5"
  }
]
```

I have an array with a list of month-year as

```
let datesArr = ['2020-08','2020-07','2020-06','2020-05','2020-04','2020-04','2020-03','2020-02','2020-01','2019-12']
```

Now i am eliminating those items from original array whose `date (on dateYear key)` does not match with the any dates specified in datesArr.

```
let filtered = mainArray.filter(value => {
    value.monthlyData = value.monthlyData.filter(md => {
        return datesArr.includes(md.dateYear);
    })
    return value.monthlyData.length > 0;
})
```

Now for example, for one element of original array if the date of the original array element does not match with any of the dates then i want to insert those dates in original array element with data key as empty.

**EDIT:**

Let's suppose i have only one element in the monthlyData array as 2018-07 & hashId parllel to that is 7 now this date does not exist in datesArr so this element should be removed from the monthlyData array but the dates in monthlyData array does not match with datesArr should be inserted into monthlyData with data key as empty

Each hashId can have data for many months so thats why monthlyData is an array.

Comment: why is your "monthlyData" an array? should it just be an object

Comment: *"Now for example"*: if this is an example, can you please state the general rule? Do you want the dates to be added also if one original date mismatches, but another original date *does* match? Or what if the original dates all match, but do not "cover" all possible dates? ...etc.

Comment: You should highlight your question more. As you can see, already two answers have been posted, which miss what you are really asking for.

Comment: Let's suppose i have only one element in the monthlyData array as 2018-07 & hashId parllel to that is 7 now this date does not exist in datesArr so this element should be removed from the monthlyData array but the dates in monthlyData array does not match with datesArr should be inserted into monthlyData with data key as empty

Comment: This really does not answer the case where the monthlyData array has multiple entries. See the scenarios I described. Please answer for each of those what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Use filter and some methods

```js
const arr = [{
    "monthlyData": [{
      "dateYear": "2020-07",
      "data": [{
        "id": "45bf4792-c5a5-44ed-b7e8-57557c4f30ee",
        "date": "2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z",
        "transactionId": "160",
        "amount": 70,
        "active": 1,
        "createdAt": "2020-07-14T02:55:43.988Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
        "version": 1
      }]
    }],
    "hashId": "4"
  },
  {
    "monthlyData": [{
      "dateYear": "20222-08",
      "data": [{
        "id": "38fe3c68-e6aa-4c57-b4d7-dc6c4f597269",
        "date": "2020-08-13T00:00:00.000Z",
        "transactionId": "146",
        "active": 1,
        "createdAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-14T02:55:43.988Z",
        "version": 1
      }]
    }],
    "hashId": "5"
  }
]

let datesArr = ['2020-08', '2020-07', '2020-06', '2020-05', '2020-04', '2020-04', '2020-03', '2020-02', '2020-01', '2019-12'];


let result = arr.filter(x => x["monthlyData"].some(y => !datesArr.some(z => z === y.dateYear)))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Let's suppose i have only one element in the monthlyData array as 2018-07 & hashId parllel to that is 7 now this date does not exist in datesArr so this element should be removed from the monthlyData array but the dates in monthlyData array does not match with datesArr should be inserted into monthlyData with data key as empty